# Send mail from any email id in android using javamail api

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail

I am using javamail api to send emails from my app. This is my code:

```
public class MailSender extends Authenticator{

private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
private String user;   
private String password;   
private Session session;   

static {   
    Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());   
}  

public MailSender(String user, String password) {   
    this.user = user;   
    this.password = password;   

    Properties props = new Properties();   
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");//587
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   //587
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   
}   

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
}

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
    try{
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
    message.setSubject(subject);   
    message.setDataHandler(handler);   
    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
    else  
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
    Transport.send(message);   
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}   

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
    private byte[] data;   
    private String type;   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
        this.type = type;   
    }   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
    }   

    public void setType(String type) {   
        this.type = type;   
    }   

    public String getContentType() {   
        if (type == null)   
            return "application/octet-stream";   
        else  
            return type;   
    }   

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
    }   

    public String getName() {   
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
    }   

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
        throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
    }   
}  }
```

And it is working fine for gmail. But i need to support other mail clients like yahoo, aol and even my company mail host. How it is possible?. I tried to change mailHost and port, but nothing happening. I need to change anything more? Please help. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: you should read javamail [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#yahoomail)

Comment: my problem still remains..

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong.  See the JavaMail FAQ entries for "common mistakes" and "debugging".

Comment: i think this one will help you
[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a